# How do you assign unique id for every checkbox?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, checkbox

i am trying to check whether are the check boxes checked. However, the problem i am facing is that i used a loop(xsl:for-each) to automatically generate the checkboxes depending on the XML. Since i am auto generating them, i cant set different IDs for every checkboxes, which prevents me from updating the specific checkbox's attribute for an indication that it is checked. Plus, whenever i checked a checkbox( be it the first or the last one), the first checkbox will be the one that gets updated. Can someone offer me a suggestion? or at least put me in a right direction? Thanks in advance.

Here is my XSLT code:

```
  <xsl:if test="$type='MultiList'">
          <xsl:for-each select="./options/item">
            <xsl:element name="input">
              <xsl:attribute name="type">checkbox</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="id">hey</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="onchange">hii()</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="score">
                <xsl:value-of select="@score"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
              </xsl:attribute>

            </xsl:element>
            <label>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </label>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>


    function hii(){

    var a = document.getElementById('hey');
    a.setAttribute("score","1");
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an id for every checkbox.

Change the function definition to accept a parameter:

```
function hii(checkbox) {
    checkbox.setAttribute("score", (checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0));
}
```

And then pass `this` to `hii()`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="onchange">hii(this)</xsl:attribute>
```

Or remove the `onclick` attribute at all and use a click handler which is attached to the parent element of your checkboxes.

Example:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("div");
parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
    return;
  }
  
  e.target.setAttribute("score", e.target.checked ? 1 : 0);
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, didnt know you can do that until now! Probably because i just started learning this language by myself thats why! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Erm, what about radiobutton? I tried to replicate this method on radiobutton but right now the value still remains 1 even when its not checked. How do you resolve that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about exactly... Maybe it is worth a separate question :)